# Using SQLcl in maven java project

Tags: java, oracle, maven, dependencies, sqlcl

I'm trying to use SQLcl in my maven Java project, but I cannot figure out how to use it.

**What I have tried so far:**

I downloaded the latest SQLcl (sqlcl-19.4.0.354.0937.zip) from [oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html).
I extracted all the files into a local folder. I then opened the sqlcl-19.4.0.354.0937\sqlcl\lib folder with terminal and ran 'mvn validate'. Maven stated that 'ucp.jar' is missing. I downloaded that jar from [oracle downloads](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-ucp-122-downloads.html) and ran it again. This time it 'seemed to run successfully'. I also tried to 'mvn clean install' with same results.

However, I'm unable to find '**dbtools-common.jar**', '**dbtools-http.jar**' or '**dbtools-sqlcl.jar**' files anywhere in my m2 folder. [This tutorial](https://barrymcgillin.blogspot.com/2018/04/sqlcl-1811-release-installing-jars-to.html) was explaining to do it like this. Intellij is unable to import classes like 'ScriptParser' because the dependencies are missing.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: were you able to do it?

Comment: @P.Waksman It's been few years, but I think I managed to get it to work :-) Those dependencies were a mess to handle. I think I ended up with some missing runtime dependencies. The only way to be sure is to take all dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

The pom `sqlcl/lib` is used for installing dependent `jars` into your local repository. However, its not for installing the `sqlcl jars` (`dbtools-*`) into your local repository.
You can certainly tweak it to do so, and use them as [@Hooman.AS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60755927/4675524) suggests.

The pom is to load the dependencies for the `jdbcrest` so that users can try out the rest `jdbc driver`.

Comment: I just want to use the java api to run sql scripts via sqlcl (like in the example code) and nothing else. Is it enough if I just add the dbtools-* jars as dependency?